# How to improve performance of unwind operation stage in mongoDb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

The aggregation is taking very long time when the total number of records increases.

```
[{
        "$unwind": {
            "path": "$arrays1",
            "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
        }
    }, {
        "$unwind": {
            "path": "$arrays2",
            "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
        }
    }, {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0
            "field1": "$field1",
            "field2": "$field2",
            "field3": "$arrays1",
            "field4": "$arrays2",
            .......
        }
    },
    {
       "$out" : "AggregatedData"
    }
]
```

As the total number of records in the collection reached 3 Million+, the aggregation is taking more than 30 minutes to complete. How can I improve the performance of this aggregation?

Comment: Your pipeline has no sense, you are flattening `array1` and `array2`, but in `$project` stage you don't do anything with it.

Comment: @Valijon Updated the aggregation stages. flattened array1 and array2 are using in project and the final output is inserted into a new collection.

Comment: @Valijon any help here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Once you flatten, you just need to copy them into new collection? Why do you need to do that periodically? Since you havve +3M records, indexing (default _id) takes much time. You need to apply some filtering (date) or some JOIN stage to filter or try `$MERGE` to insert only new records which may help you.